# sp_executesql Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I execute the following query I have an error message like 
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

This error occurs only in SQL Server 2012 and not in SQL Server 2005

```
exec sp_executesql 
   N'INSERT INTO tablename 
        ([id], [ParentId], [Path], [Filename]) 
     VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3);'
    ,N'@p0 uniqueidentifier
    ,@p1 uniqueidentifier
    ,@p2 nvarchar(4000)'
    ,@p3 nvarchar(4000)'
    ,@p0='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    ,@p1='11111111-1111-1111-1111-1111111111111'
    ,@p2=N'path'
    ,@p3=N'name'
```

Comment: My guess would be that your table data types are incorrect (e.g. perhaps filename is a datetime instead of nvarchar(4000)? otherwise, the query would work as expected).

Comment: ZLK you are right. There is a difference with the column type and the variable type. Thank you